# Java functional programming way to justify text Stream<Integer>

Tags: java, functional-programming

I am trying to print out a long list of numbers so that each line is about the same length, i.e. never more than say 80 characters wide. I'm trying to learn the functional aspects of Java so thought I would convert my procedural version to use streams and lambdas etc. It seems difficult to get it right at the end because I don't know when I'm processing the last entry. Is this doable? And is it a reasonable thing to try to do this way? (suspecting not)

Here is my procedural version:

```
private static void printWholeListLimitedWidth(List<Integer> list, int width) {
    final int maxWidth = width;
    int lineWidth = 0;
    StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder(width);
    for (Integer n : list) {
        String toPrint = String.format("%d, ", n);
        if (line.length() + toPrint.length() > width) {
            System.out.println(line.toString());
            line.delete(0, line.length());
        }
        line.append(toPrint);
    }
    if (line.length() > 0) {
        System.out.println(line.toString());
    }
}
```

And here is my attempt at a functional version:

```
private static void printWholeListLimitedWidthFunctional(List<Integer> list, int width) {

    list.stream().forEach(new Consumer<Integer>() {
        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder(width);
        public void accept(Integer j) {
            String toPrint = String.format("%d, ", j);
            if (line.length() + toPrint.length() > width) {
                System.out.println(line.toString());
                line.delete(0, line.length());
            }
            line.append(toPrint);
        }
    });
}
```

The functional version runs, but leaves off the last few numbers. I realize it is because I don't have anything equivalent to the if statement after the loop in the procedural version, but don't see a better way to know where the end than processing the list twice.

Comment: The first thing to get rid of in your second snippet is maintaining state in the code run iteratively. This mindset goes a long way when programming in functional style. Then... please use a lambda expression and not an anonymous class for such a functional interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ernest_k mentioned, avoid creating instances inside iteration, moving `StringBuilder` outside will help to achieve your result, also take the full advantages of lambda expression for concise code

```
   //StringBuilder should be outside the lambda scope, do not create instance everytime
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(); 
    list.stream().forEach(i -> { //using as lambda
         //your toPrint is always of length 3, no need create extra variable
         if(temp.length() + 3 > width){ 
              System.out.println(temp.toString());
              temp.delete(0, temp.length());
          }
          //directly append it
           temp.append(i).append(", "); 
     });
     //finally you can manually check and print pending
     if(temp.length() > 0){
         System.out.println(temp);
     }
```

Comment: This works for me, key idea being to pull the StringBuilder out into the enclosing function. On the matter of having the lambda vs an anonymous Consumer, I suppose that it is a matter of style and conciseness, since I think that the lambda actually is a more concisely expressed anonymous Consumer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a collector in this case, something like this

```
private static void printNumbersLimited(List<Integer> numbers, int width) {
    System.out.println(numbers.stream()
            .map(number -> String.format("%d ", number))
            .collect(() -> new NumberFormatter(width), NumberFormatter::append, NumberFormatter::merge).complete());
}

private static class NumberFormatter {
    private final int width;
    private int length;
    private final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    public NumberFormatter(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public String complete() {
        return (builder.toString());
    }

    public void append(String s) {
        if (length + s.length() > width) {
            length = 0;
            builder.append('\n');
        }
        builder.append(s).append(" ");
        length += s.length();
    }

    public void merge(NumberFormatter other) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```